# how do i have to do? "Failed to load plugin '@testing-library' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module '@testing-library/eslint-plugin'"

Tags: react-testing-library, eslintrc

My error message is:

> Failed to load plugin '@testing-library' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module '@testing-library/eslint-plugin'

`eslintrc.json`:

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:@testing-library",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:@testing-library/jest-dom"
  ],
"plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "@testing-library/jest-dom","prettier","@testing-library/react","@testing-library/eslint-plugin"],
```

How do i fix it?
I already tried delete nodemodules and reinstall `yarn`,
also I tried add and delete `@testing-library/eslint-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try dropping the *eslint-plugin* portion of '**@testing-library/eslint-plugin**' per their [docs](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library#:%7E:text=Add%20testing%2Dlibrary%20to%20the%20plugins%20section%20of%20your%20.eslintrc.js%20configuration%20file.%20You%20can%20omit%20the%20eslint%2Dplugin%2D%20prefix%3A).
You can also specify the framework you are using [docs](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library#:%7E:text=Since%20each%20one,with%20DOM%20one).